# Can Jenkins controller performance impact Agent performance?

Tags: jenkins

If controller already initiated a job on an agent and now controller is facing performance issues (low memory or High CPU usage), will the execution on agent be impacted?
As there is data transfer (such as logs, libraries, artifacts from other runs) between controller and agent is happening during job execution, wondering if data transfer is impacted and as a result, agent waits for data from controller?

To fix the performance issue in this case, below seemed to work.
Controller - Garbage collection executed which cleared available memory on Controller.